# Python - extract numbers and commas from string (with re.sub)

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following string (Python) :

```
test = "    +30,0 EUR abcdefgh   "
```

I want to remove everything but numbers and comma ",".

```
Expected result: "30.0"
```

So based on [re doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) I tried :

```
test = re.sub('^[0-9,]', "", test)
```

Output is:

```
"    +30,0 EUR abcdefgh   "
```

Nothing happened. Why?

Comment: Remove the `^` in your expression, the +30 isn't at the start of the string. And you probably want `''.join(re.findall("[0-9,]", test))`

Comment: I thought "^" means "NOT" ? Here, the regex I want is "everything but "0-9,". I thought "^" was useful in this case

Comment: Apparently, in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34833549/5775381) answer, it works. But as he said, it has to be inside the brackets, or it just interprets it as the beginning of the line.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html): _Characters that are not within a range can be matched by complementing the set. If the first character of the set is '^', all the characters that are not in the set will be matched. For example, [^5] will match any character except '5', and [^^] will match any character except '^'. ^ has no special meaning if it’s not the first character in the set._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `^` needs to go inside the brackets.

```
>>> re.sub('[^0-9,]', "", test)
'30,0'
```

To change the comma to a decimal:

```
>>> '30,0're.sub('[^0-9,]', "", test).replace(",", ".")
'30.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want get the output with `"."`, you can try this:

```
test = re.sub('[^0-9.]', "", test.replace(",","."))

test

'30.0'
```